# Intuition behind convolution identity for Laplace transforms

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, laplace-transform, convolution

Convolutions, relatively speaking, are fairly straightforward for simple systems (from an applied perspective), but I cannot, at all, find the intuition behind the Laplace identity for convolutions. That is:

$$
\mathcal{L}\{f\star g\}=\mathcal{L}\{f\}\cdot \mathcal{L}\{g\}
$$

How is it possible to make sense of this? Perhaps there is some probability theory example that sheds light on it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you multiply two power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n}$, then a type of convolution also appears because of trying to gather like powers
$$
         \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}z^{n} =
           \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}b_{n-k}\right)z^{n}
$$
You can think of a Laplace transform as a continuous version of a power series for the purposes of this discussion built from powers $e^{-ns}=(e^{-s})^{n}$.
$$
      \int_{0}^{\infty}a(n)e^{-n s}\,dn \int_{0}^{\infty}b(n)e^{-ns}\,dn =
     \int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{n}a(k)b(n-k)\,dk\right)e^{-ns}\,dn.
$$
The Laplace transform identity then gives
$$
           \mathcal{L}\{ a\} \mathcal{L}\{ b\} = \mathcal{L}\{ a\star b\}.
$$
The proof of the convolution identity follows the pattern of dealing with power series by changing the order of integration (instead of summation) in order to collect like powers. So the analogy is strong. I'm not sure if this is the type of intuition you're looking for or not.

**Hardy Space Mapping:** Suppose $f \in L^{2}[0,\infty)$. Then the Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)$ of $f$ is holomorphic in the right half-plane, and is uniformly bounded on $\Re s \ge \delta > 0$. Furthermore, $G_{u}(v)=\mathcal{L}\{f\}(u+iv)$ is in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ for each $u > 0$. This is because $G_{u}(v)$ is really the Fourier transform (to within a constant) of $e^{-ut}f(t)$ for fixed $u$. So, by Parsevel's equality,
$$
      \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|G_{u}(v)|^{2}\,dv=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2ut}|f(t)|^{2}\,dt \le \|f\|^{2}_{L^{2}[0,\infty)}
$$
So that means $G$ is in the hardy space $H^{2}(\Pi^{+})$ where $\Pi^{+}$ is the right half-plane. Furthermore,
$$
                   \frac{1}{2\pi}\|\mathcal{L}\{f\}\|_{H^{2}}=\|f\|_{L^{2}}.
$$
And the boundary function of this Hardy class function is $L^{2}-\lim_{u\downarrow 0}G_{u}=\mathcal{F}f$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform of the function which is $0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ and is $f$ on $[0,\infty)$. On the other hand, every $f \in H^{2}$ has an $L^{2}$ boundary function $f_{0}$, which allows the Cauchy integral representation
$$
\begin{align}
   f(s) & = -\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f_{0}(iu)}{iu-s}\,du \\
      & =-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{0}(iu)\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{t(iu-z)}\,dt\,du \\
      & =\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{0}(iu) e^{itu}\,du\right)e^{-ts}\,dt.
\end{align}
$$
So the correspondence between $H^{2}(\Pi^{+})$ is $L^{2}[0,\infty)$ is fully unitary.

So $f \in H^{2}(\Pi^{+})$ iff there exists $h \in L^{2}[0,\infty$ such that
$$
            f(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zt}h(t)\,dt.
$$
If $k \in L^{1}[0,\infty)$, then
$$
                K(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-zt}k(t)\,dt
$$
is a bounded holomorphic function on the right half-plane. And $K(z)$ is a valid multiplier on $H^{2}$ that is equivalent to a convolution operator:
$$
       F(z)f(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\left( e^{-zt}\int_{0}^{t}k(u)h(t-u)\,du\right)\,dt
$$
This is part of the functional calculus.

Comment: Not quite, I was wondering more for graphical intuition or something that could kind-of reveal the relationship between these operations in terms of the underlying transformations performed on the functions? That is, of course, if it is possible.

Comment: @Guillermo Angeris Can you elaborate more about what you mean? What I have shown you is that you can view the function in the Laplace transform as a coefficient of powers of an exponential, and that's why convolution is needed: you have to gather like powers when you multiply two such expansions in order to write the product as a single such expression. So I'm still not clear on what you have in mind instead.

Comment: Yeah, I've definitely seen this explanation before. What I was wondering is if it is possible to, in some sense, visualize how the identity works on functions. For example, it's easy to visualize the convolution as the area of the intersecting curves, but how would the Laplace transform affect this?

Perhaps it is better to see it as follows: is it possible to visualize the operation in the same way that we can visualize Fourier transforms as spectral decompositions on the convolution?

Comment: The Laplace transform is the spectral decomposition of differentiation on the half line. Differentiation is not selfadjoint on the half line, and that changes the nature of the decomposition. But the reason for the exponentials is that they are eigefunctions. The spectral transform maps $L^{2}$ functions on the half line to the Hardy space of holomorphic functions on the right half plane with uniformly bounded $L^{2}$ norms on vertical lines. So the Laplace transform builds a holomorphic function as a continuous sum, much as I described. The transform turns differentiation into multiplication.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! Could you elaborate a little more on the Hardy space mapping? I'm not quite sure I get the logical jump...

Comment: @Guillermo Angeris : I added more for you on the Hardy space.

Comment: That makes quite a bit more sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well convolutions are really DEFINED to make that identity true. Their use comes into play when you want to separate the elements of the equations that relate to the system itself,  those that relate to the initial conditions of the system, and those that relate to external forces. For example, consider

$$ ay''+by'+cy = g(x) $$

Transforming,

$$a\big (s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)\big ) + b\big (sY(s) - y(0) \big ) + cY(s) = G(s) $$

Now let

$$H(s)=\frac 1{as^2+bs+c}$$
$$C(s) = sy(0)+y'(0)+y(0)$$

Then $Y(s) = G(s)H(s) + C(s)H(s) $ and using our definition of convolution,

$$y(x) = g(x) ⋆ h(x) + c(x) ⋆ h(x) $$

If the convolution is easier to calculate than the inverse transform, then the convolution theorem can be used to simplify things and separate the aspects of the equations logically.

I'll try to review this post when I'm not so tired in the morning.