# Why is convolution in the time domain equal to multiplication in the frequency domain? (intuitively, not mathematically)

Tags: calculus, fourier-transform, intuition, convolution

I know the logic of how Fourier transforms work, and I know the logic of how convolution works, but I can't figure out why convolution in the time domain is equal to multiplication in the frequency domain. I am looking for a logical/intuitive answer, not a mathematical proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn’t a complete answer to your question, but in the discrete case, this video gives some really nice intuition for what convolution is (and what it has to do with time vs frequency etc)

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KuXjwB4LzSA

Comment: Why the downvote? If it's because a great answer exists elsewhere then link it! If not then questions like this sometimes get brilliantly informative answers; I would upvote!

Comment: In general, ignore down votes: they make no sense and convey no useful information.

Comment: [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2041695/why-does-convolution-become-multiplication-when-taking-the-fourier-transform) should answer your question.

Comment: And [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880207/intuition-behind-convolution-identity-for-laplace-transforms) hopefully helps further.